# Why is this logging configuration not printing to stdout?

Tags: python, django

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
    },
    'simple': {
        'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        'strm': sys.stdout,
        'formatter':'simple'
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers':['console'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'INFO',
    }, 
    #'django.request': {
    #    'handlers': ['console'],
    #    'level': 'ERROR',
    #    'propagate': True,
    #},
},
}
```

Tried both out loggers, active and the one commented out (and many others).
Running

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

And yet no strack trace on a 500 error printed my console, just:

```
[21/Feb/2012 04:21:10] "POST /some/path/function/ HTTP/1.1" 500 105627
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `filters`:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers':['console'],
        'filters': [],             # <-- this line
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'INFO',
    },
},
```

I don't know why.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this myself. For some reason, AFAIK, the filters field is the only one that is somehow set automagically by django to ['require_debug_false'], if they're not specified, at least when using mail_admins handler. I discovered this by trial and error and lot of headscratching. I am not sure whether this is intended behavior or a bug (Django 1.4.x)

Comment: Ah, interesting findings @TomášPlešek

Answer (score 2):

Logger level has higher priority to handler level,
logging.DEBUG has value 10, and logging.INFO has value 20.

```
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
    },
}

'loggers': {
        'level':'INFO',
    }
```

Hence your logging is always set at INFO level coz of logger priority, and DEBUG output will not be used.

this is what i feels is the issue.

Comment: Sure, if I set the logger level down to DEBUG, I can get DEBUG output.  I don't want debug output.  I want INFO and above, but really what I want is error.  There is no ERROR level logging at all.

Comment: logging.ERROR is there with a value of 40, check it out in the logging module. try, import logging
logging.ERROR

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to dig out, but it's because of this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#request-exceptions-are-now-always-logged

It's quite confusing and should be highlighted in the logs documentation, which it isn't.