# Does Azure Streaming logs feature support python?

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-diagnostics

I am developing a Django web app on Azure platform. I am wondering is the Streaming logs feature on Azure supported for python Django. I tried logging.error(msg) but nothing display in the log. Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, you want to get the error level logging from the diagnostic log stream of Kudu service using Python.

As I known, you can refer to the wiki page [`Diagnostic Log Stream`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream) of Kudu project on GitHub to know how to get error logging via the tool `curl`.

The steps as below, and the variable `<kudu-service-url>` is `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsite.net`.

1. Setting the trace level, such as for error level, `curl <kudu-service-url>/settings -X POST -H "Content-Type: Application/json" -d "{'trace_level':'4'}"`.
2. Checking the trace level, `curl <kudu-service-url>/settings/trace_level`.
3. Getting the streaming logs, `curl -u {username} https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/logstream`. The variable `username` is your Azure Publishing user (same as you use for git publishing).

Note: For the steps 1 & 2, please see the section [`trace_level knobs`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream#trace_level-knobs) for more details.

So you can try to do the above steps using Python with package like `urllib2` or [`PycURL`](http://pycurl.io/).

---

**Update**:

Try to follow the SO thread [Django logging to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134895/django-logging-to-console) to enable logging to console for Django, then read the log streaming for Django application.

Comment: I think it's the other way around, the OP wants to read the log messages produced by the Python/Django code within the Streaming logs tool.

Comment: Note I had to add my username (via the -u option) when setting and checking the trace level.