# Django filter on attribute with two values, preferring the result of one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

This is kind of a weird question, so sorry in advance. I have a model in Django Rest that looks like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Foo(BaseModel):
    barId = models.ForeignKey(Bar, unique=False)
    fizzId = models.ForeignKey(Fizz, unique=False)
    buzzId = models.IntegerField(unique=False)
    value = models.TextField()
```

And I have a ViewSet that needs to return a list of all the Foos that have a given {request_barId, request_buzzId, lastUpdateDate}. This is fairly straightforward,

```
foobar = Foo.objects.filter(
buzzId=request_buzzId,
modified_date__gt=request_lastUpdateDate,
barId=request_barId)
```

Here's the rub. There's a default value for buzzId that is the **base list** that the specified buzzId needs to overlay, replacing the instances on the base list. That's where I'm getting a little lost. I have a solution, but I feel like it's not particularly elegant and that there's go to be a way to do this cleaner. Here's my code to do the overlay:

```
base_foobar = Foo.objects.filter(
buzzId=base_buzzId,
modified_date__gt=request_lastUpdateDate,
barId=request_barId).exclude(
        fizzId__in=[o.fizzId for o in foobar])
result = foobar | base_foobar
```

And this just seems really janky. Is there a way to clean this up?

EDIT: To clarify, let's say that the list for the tuple { 1, 0, '01-01-1970' } represents the base set (buzzId: 0), and returns a list of objects containing fizzIds { 1, 2, 3, 10 }. Let's say that the tuple { 1, 1, '01-01-1970' } represents some buzzId's request for a complete set of strings. If we say that our buzzId of 1 (call it augment) has matching Foos with fizzIds { 2, 10, 15, 20 }, then our result set should look like

```
{ (base) 1, (augment) 2, (base) 3, (augment) 10, (augment) 15, (augment) 20 }
```

Does this clear it up?

Comment: can you please elaborate on this and update your question: 
"There's a default value for buzzId that is the base list that the specified buzzId needs to overlay, replacing the instances on the base list."

Comment: @DhruvBaveja updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#q-objects) to combine into one statement:

```
result = (Foo.objects
    .filter(
        Q(
            modified_date__gt=request_lastUpdateDate,
            barId=request_barId
        ) 
        &
        (
            Q(buzzId=request_buzzId) 
            |
            (
                Q(buzzId=base_buzzId)
                & 
                ~Q(fizzId__in=[o.fizzId for o in foobar])
            )
        )
    )
    .order_by( '-buzzId' if request_buzzId < base_buzzId else 'buzzId')
    )[0] # fetch first result only
```

Also, please format all your code in the future.  It doesn't have to be like me, but it would definitely help with reading your question.

Comment: Do apologise on the formatting; I tried to fix it in the editor and I guess editing screwed it up or something. I'll fix it. Will also try your solution out, thanks!

Comment: No prob, I see you're newbie :-)  If the solution helps, up vote it.  If it works, up vote it and accept it :-)

Comment: So the solution I have right now does work. I'm wondering if you can explain why this solution would be a better one than what I have listed? Does it optimize the query, or is there an efficiency I'm missing?

Comment: There is probably little difference, but you should look at the generated SQL by printing it out to your console.  I do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22134895/20712) in my environment to _always_ print out the SQL in debug/non-production mode.  The only "optimization" that I've done is to implement [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by putting the common filter terms into a single `Q()`.  Also, by using one filter, instead of two, complex relationship following filter parameters are executed against one related table instance instead of rejoining.

Comment: Anyways. Spit out the SQL and then measure it in whatever database engine you're using.  Then look at the query schedule et c., et c.